# How to expose a file on network storage via some endpoint (controller) in blazor?

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

I'm using PDF.js in my Blazor server application, and it works fine with local files, but now I want to find a way to get pdf files on a network storge to expose them via some endpoint (controller) so that can do a GET request for them. I found some sample code, but most of them are using some content instead of a file path on a storage, like this:

["SaveAsFile" sample code using blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683706/how-can-one-generate-and-save-a-file-client-side-using-blazor)

```
function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

can anyone help me for changing the usage of a file path instead of bytesbase64 in "*saveAsFile*" in above example code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that ASP.NET Core has support for this [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization) without necessitating the use of a controller for this purpose via the `UseStaticFiles()` method in `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices()` per the following example:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseStaticFiles(); //Makes js, css, and images available without authentication
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("//server/share/file.pdf"),
    RequestPath = "/pdfs"
  });
}
```

Now, just make your GET call to `://example.com/pdfs/file.pdf` and you'll serve the actual file back to them, complete with authentication support.