Blazor WASM app open PDF memorystream in another browser tab
I believe that this code may be a way to open a base64 encoded PDF file into another browser tab or window.  However, when I try on my Windows PC using Edge browser, a new tab appears that is blank, and the PC CPU starts running more until I close the browser.  The PDF document does not appear. The downloadFile scrip does work. We want to use an open script.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdf.Save(memoryStream);
                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                string url = $"data:application/pdf;base64,{base64}";
                JS.InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "_blank");
            }

I also tried a similar method to downloadFile instead of open.  Again, the browser did not indicate that a file download was happening, and the PC CPU started running more until I closed the browser.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdf.Save(memoryStream);

                JS.InvokeAsync<object>(
                   "downloadFile",
                   uid + ".pdf",
                   Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
                );
            };

This downloadFile script is used.
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadFile(fileName, bytesBase64) {
            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                var data = window.atob(bytesBase64);
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                var blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
            else {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.download = fileName;
                link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function open(bytesBase64) {
            var blob = base64ToBlob(bytesBase64, "application/octet-stream");
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url, "_blank");
        }

        function base64ToBlob(base64, contentType) {
            var byteCharacters = atob(base64);
            var byteArrays = [];

            for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 512) {
                var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 512);

                var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }

            var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
            return blob;
        }
    </script>


For good browser support your URL should not exceed 2048 characters. I guess a base64 encoded PDF can easily exceed that limit and it might be the reason for failure

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594218/5265292 it might help since it uses URL.createObjectURL instead of trying to fit the whole filecontent into the URL

I think I see the issue. I was able to create a very simplified working version here. This is in javascript but should get the point across.
Key differences:

I changed "application/octet-stream" to "application/pdf" everywhere. Rather than use a generic MIME type like octet-stream, you can be more verbose to specify exactly what you want.
Updated variable scoping.
Used sample data.

Number 3 might be the key to your cpu issue as well. Ensure you are testing several PDF's from very small to large to ensure you are managing memory wisely, don't rely entirely on the garbage collector.
